# Balance algorithm methods with Redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I have 2-n implementations of similar Axios requests, named as functions `Method1`, `Method2` .... `MethodN`.

So I have a common method "makeRequest" that should choose a certain method to call and support balance between methods. All methods should be called approximately the same count of times.

How to do it with Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted set could be helpful for this but first you need to migrate(initialize) your methods to a sorted set with their initial scores. For simplicity i assumed you have three methods. Since method names are unique, `set` will fit to your use case. `Score` will be used to keep track of the number of usages.

- By using `ZADD` set `0` score for each method. (initialize, will be done once)
- Use `ZRANGE methods 0 0` to get the lowest scored method (used less)
- After getting the method name with ZRANGE, use `ZINCRBY` to increment score of the method (increment usage count)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD methods 0 method1 0 method2 0 method3
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE methods 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "method1"
2) "0"
3) "method2"
4) "0"
5) "method3"
6) "0"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE methods 0 0
1) "method1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY methods 1 method1
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE methods 0 0
1) "method2"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY methods 1 method2
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE methods 0 0
1) "method3"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZINCRBY methods 1 method3
"1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE methods 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "method1"
2) "1"
3) "method2"
4) "1"
5) "method3"
6) "1"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE methods 0 0
1) "method1"
```

Comment: I have created a repository doing the same things
https://github.com/dmitryuk/RedisFunctionsBalancer